# Dllnotfoundexception when build a unity3d project towards android on Mac

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine

The unity version is 2017.1.3.p4

The import so codes are as follows:

```
public const string LibName = "GCloudVoice";

[DllImport(LibName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 private static extern int GCloudVoice_CreateInstance();
```

and the path of so is as follows:

```
PROJECT_ROOT/Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libGCloudVoice.so
```

The so configurations on unity are as follows:

[image: THE SO CONFIGURATIONS]

the so file information:

```
libGCloudVoice.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, stripped
```

I doubt that unity does not search the so in the so path at all.

Comment: I've tried to build on Mac before. I suggest you file for a bug report with your current project. It looks like the dll is not being included in the final build

Comment: I think the project should find the so library,why it try to find a dll towards android platform??

Comment: Like I said it it looks like the dll is not being included in the final build or the error is coming from somewhere. Your only option left is filing for a bug report from the Editor. Before you do that, download the [sample](https://github.com/DavidSheh/GVoiceDemo) project and see if it works. If it works, then you can start with it. If not, file for a bug report